# Is it possible in C++ to declare an attibute in the body?

Tags: c++

Is it possible in C++ to declare an attibute in the body, that is, the .cpp file ?

Comment: In general, when your terminology is really weak, try to provide an example of what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by `attribute`, you mean `member variable` of a class, then the answer is: "member variables must be defined in the class definition." They cannot be defined anywhere else, neither in the constructor, or in any member function.

Whether the class definition sits in the header file or in the source (.cpp) file is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add an attribute to a class outside the original definition of the class (which is usually in a header), for example in the `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
test.cpp:

class Test
{
   int x; //declare attribute in class body and in cpp file
};
```